# Why does the fingerprint of a GPG key change after it is made a sub key?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, openpgp, fingerprint

I recently consolidated some of my independently GPG keys.

I used the following the command to edit the oldest key

```
gpg --expert --edit-key <oldest-keygrip>
gpg> add-key --keygrip=<another-keygrip>
```

After that I exported and deleted all the newer keys that had been converted into subkeys.

I noticed that the fingerprint of the subkey changes but the keygrip remains unchanged. Why?

Would it affect decrypting past messages that were encrypted for the non-subkey? According to the PGP RFCs the fingerprint is in the header of the encrypted document.